# Jquery hover function does not always get called on hover over

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have a jquery hover problem, for some reason hover function does not always get called every time I hover over an `li` in my case.

Here I have a navigation as

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when I hover over the `li` I want to change the background color of the hover `li`.

Here is my jquery functions

```
var colorArray = [ "#2E8B57", "#008080", "#FF4500", "#FF7F50", "#C71585", "#FFD700", "#FF1493", "D7578B" ];
$("#nav ul li").hover(function(event){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8));
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": colorArray[rand],
            WebkitTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MozTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            OTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MsTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            transition: 'background-color 500ms linear'
        });
    },function(){
    $(this).css({
            "background-color": '#FFFFFF',
            WebkitTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MozTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            OTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MsTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            transition: 'background-color 500ms linear'
     });
});
```

**Most of the time it works but for some reason sometimes the background color of the `li` does not change.**

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vu1m50at/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last color `D7578B` misses the `#`. That color will probably not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
var colorArray = [ "#2E8B57", "#008080", "#FF4500", "#FF7F50", "#C71585", "#FFD700", "#FF1493", "#D7578B" ];
$("#nav ul li").hover(function(event){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8));
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": colorArray[rand],
            WebkitTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MozTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            OTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MsTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            transition: 'background-color 500ms linear'
        });
    },function(){
    $(this).css({
            "background-color": '#FFFFFF',
            WebkitTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MozTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            OTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            MsTransition: 'background-color 500ms linear',
            transition: 'background-color 500ms linear'
        });

    });
```

[HERE MY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/vu1m50at/3/)